# symfony 4 public files not accesible

Tags: php, iis, symfony4

When deploying to test server I cannot access anything in the public folder. I get the Symfony Route error. As if it doesn't recognize the public folder. All pages route correctly. My dev environment is the following c:\inetpub\wwroot\userdir\symfony-test
Which translates to this url. https://servername/userdir/symfony-test/test

Trying to pull up the test image below or the css or js files in twig I get a 404 error

```
 <img src="{{  asset('build/images/test.jpg')   }}"  alt="test">
```

Seeing that it was not getting the full path I changed the framwork.yaml to set the base_urls which gives the full path and I set the json manifest_path. While the manifest path is correct and I can see that it gives the full path on using base_urls I still get a 404 for anything in the public folder.

```
assets:
    json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
    base_urls:
      - 'https://servername/userdir/symfony-test/public/'
```

Doing the above resulted in

```
GET https://servername/userdir/symfony-test/build/images/test.93d146a7.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I also updated the composer.json file as below to add the public-dir under "extra" following the link instructions here. https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html

```
 "extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.2.*",
        "public-dir": "userdir/symfony-test/public/"
    }
```

Files are compiled using encore webpack and works as expected.

`Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .enableVersioning()
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('test','./assets/images/test.jpg')`

This might be helpful information too.
Here is the rule in the /public/web.config file.

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

Rule in symfony-test/web.config

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name="Symfony4" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="public/" appendQueryString="true" />
         </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Running Symfony 4 on IIS Windows Server 2012 R2.
Php 7.2.13,
Composer version 1.6.5, 
node version 8.11.4, 
yarn 1.9.4

How can I get the public folder to be recognized and not considered a route or receive a 404.

Comment: Hmm....  `IIS Windows Server 2012 R2` - I don't use windows server, but if it was Linux my first question would be who owns the folder, what are the permissions etc...  Not that I ever uploaded anything as root and couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work... nope never done that...  :-p

Comment: How did you configure the directories? Is there some equivalent of `htaccess`?

Comment: On the public directory "Everyone" has Read & execute/Read and List Folder contents with IIS_IUSRS having elevated permissions.

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the two rules on the web.config files in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone setting up an iis environment for symfony 2 on github. After accounting for directory structure I added these rules to my web.config file and now it works as expected. Hopefully this helps anyone else for whatever reasons wants to use symfony on iis :) .

```
<rules>
                <rule name="TempRewriteToWeb" stopProcessing="false">                                  
                    <match url="^(public/)?(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>      
                <rule name="StaticFiles" stopProcessing="true">                                  
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"/>                        
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>                         
               <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(public/)(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php?{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
                </rule>           
            </rules>
```